# What was Clara's reply when asked for her name on Trenzalore?

Tags: dialogue, doctor-who

In The Time of the Doctor:

When answering to the question what her name was while still being unaware of the truth field, Clara spurts out something, I couldn't make out even after several re-watches of both the original and the German dubbed version. But it definitely wasn't "Clara Oswin Oswald". It sounded more like a string of techno-babble or a machine designation.

I have read tons of reviews and am baffled that not a single one has picked up on this as it felt like one of the biggest mind-blowers in that episode for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was pretty sure that she said

> "Wobbly personality masking bossy control-freak."

using VLC to do a much slower playback, but according to [this transcript site](http://www.chakoteya.net/doctorwho/34-2.htm) and [this site](http://www.doctorwho.tv/whats-new/article/12-quotes-we-loved-from-the-time-of-the-doctor/):

> CLARA: Bubbly personality masking bossy control freak.

Given the history of Wibbly-Wobbly-Timey-Wimey stuff, "Wobbly" seemed likely. Having played it again, I do concede that "bubbly" is indeed what she said.

Comment: Hmm, but as an answer to the question "what is your name?" that wouldn't be correct, would it? It might fit if the question was instead "who are you?" (or was it? I couldn't check right now)

Comment: Well, as to the workings of the truth field there are a couple of other inconsistencies as well: It shouldn't have been possible for the Doctor to tell Barnable that he had a plan, just to tell Clara that he hasn't immediately afterwards. Either one had to have been a lie. Also, though not mentioned again in this episode, the original prophecy included the clause "nor fail to give answer" which would go against the numerous instances where someone simply said nothing instead of answering. Anyway, I'll try the VLC-slowdown myself once I'm back at my machine at home tonight.

Comment: Keep in mind the woman asked "what did you say your name was?" Not "what is your name?" As Clara hadn't said her name, her more personal revelation makes sense.

Comment: Right, I've done the VLC test at 0.33x playspeed myself now. I still can't really make out the English original except for the "control freak" bit at the end. The German dub is slightly more clearly understandable as "Ich bin überdreht und verberg' 'nen Kontrolltick" and roughly translates to "I'm unhinged and I'm concealing a control fetish" so your interpretation is probably pretty close to the actual dialogue.

Comment: However, this still doesn't make any sense at all to me: If all the truth field enforced was that you uttered *some* truth rather than the actual correct answer to the question you're asked, then, when asked about the colour of the sky, you would still be able to answer "green" because that would be a correct answer to the question "what colour is grass?".... which would render the entire truth enforcement pretty pointless in my book. What Clara (probably) said had absolutely nothing to do with the question she got asked. Period.

Comment: I disagree, but I also didn't write the thing. I'm just trying to answer the question of *what* she said as per your original post.

Comment: OK, finally found something here (offical BBC site AFAICT): http://www.doctorwho.tv/whats-new/article/12-quotes-we-loved-from-the-time-of-the-doctor/ (see number 4). You were pretty close it seems. ;) If you could edit that in I'll accept.

Comment: My answer is changed to reflect the new information. Glad you asked about this as it was bugging me when I watched it, but then I forgot.

Comment: Note that in the same scene, the Doctor felt the need to say he's wearing a wig. He even repeated it at a point where it was completely irrelevant. (Later, when dealing with the wooden Cyberman, the Doctor is able to hold back crucial information, the sonic not working on wood) The two townspeople also make it clear that you need to get used to the forcefield. Likely, Clara's **initial** exposure to the forcefield caused lowered inhibitions (as she could previously rely on thinking something different from what she's saying, which is what she **tried** to do here, but ended up blurting it out)

Comment: @OliverGiesen: Likely, the truth field merely forces you to **say what you think**. If you killed a man and are trying to hide it, and I ask you if you've killed a man, your brain's first thought will be "Yes. But let's say no". The force field **forces** that "Yes" to be said out loud (and likely also blocks you from saying "No", which you know is a lie), thus making you spill your beans. This explains Clara's comment about herself, and also the Doctor's need to (twice) point out he's wearing a wig.

Answer (score -3):

something (very fast) multiple personality control freak.
OK after listening again I will accept "Bubbly personality masking bossy control freak."

Comment: I'm not sure why you posted this as an answer. I used a player to slow it down and listen to it, and referenced sites that had transcriptions. I don't mean to sound rude, but this doesn't even warrant being a comment. It doesn't seem to add anything. I'd suggest looking at the Tour under the help menu above. Hint: since reading the Tour gives you a badge, and you have no badges, it's obvious when someone has not read it. ;)